# Can not convert to same interface in different libraries

Tags: c#, identityserver3

I'm using IdentityServer3 and I need to slightly tweak SessionCookie so I'm overriding it https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/blob/master/source/Core/Configuration/Hosting/SessionCookie.cs

My code looks like :

```
using IdentityServer3.Core.Configuration;
using IdentityServer3.Core.Configuration.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Owin;

namespace LoginServer.IdentityServer
{
    public class CustomSessionCookie : SessionCookie
    {
        public CustomSessionCookie(IOwinContext ctx, IdentityServerOptions options) : base(ctx, options)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

but I'm getting the error:

> Error CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from
>   'Microsoft.Owin.IOwinContext
>   [C:\identity\packages\Microsoft.Owin.3.0.1\lib\net45\Microsoft.Owin.dll]'
>   to 'Microsoft.Owin.IOwinContext
>   [C:\identity\packages\IdentityServer3.2.5.4\lib\net45\IdentityServer3.dll]'

in packages config for my project:

> <package id="Microsoft.Owin" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net452" />

is the same as in identityserver3

> <package id="IdentityServer3" version="2.5.4" targetFramework="net452" />

Why am I getting this error and how do I fix it?

Comment: If the interfaces are in different assemblies, they are not the same interface.

Comment: You can't "tweak" an interface you don't own, You can create a wrapper or adapter or use some other pattern but interfaces are immutable.

Comment: @DStanley Identityserver uses dependency injection well so I'm hoping to find a way to inject my CustomSessionCookie as a SessionCookie , something like  builder.Register(c => new SessionCookie(c.Resolve<IOwinContext>(), c.Resolve<IdentityServerOptions>()));

Comment: @DStanley Looks like for many of the other options I can't change the default factory for SessionCookie so I'm going to have to find a different solution.

Comment: @MattRowland They both come from Microsoft.Owin package though. One just comes with one degree of separation.

Comment: @Jeff I was thinking you had created an identically named interface - I did not catch that they were both MS libraries.  In any case they are still different interfaces (since they come from different assemblies) so you can't substitute one for the other.